# How can i configure jboss 5 to archive logs at startup?

Tags: java, log4j, jboss5.x

Hello boys and gals
how can i configure jboss 5 to archive the current logs at startup.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at a clean installation of JBoss 5.1, you'll see in JBOSS_HOME/server/default/conf/jbos-log4j that the appender for writing the server.log file is using a DailyRollingfileAppender with parameter Append=true, meaning the server will always append log messages and each day produce a new file - so that seems to me sufficient for your needs?

Comment: yep buddy you'r right but i want to zip the old log (before shutdown)

Comment: In that case just extend the startup script from jboss and add a zip command to it.